# Why are kidney discard rates so high?

Tags: human-biology, immunology, medicine, organs, mhc

A [recent report from UNOS](https://www.unos.org/early-data-suggest-kidney-allocation-system-meeting-key-expectations-2/) states:

> The kidney discard rate has returned to pre-KAS levels, dropping from 20.2 percent in the first six months to 18.4 percent in months 7-10.

To me, this seems quite high considering the number of people waiting for a kidney. Why is this rate not lower?

Comment: If you click through the link on the page you linked to is a presentation, https://www.transplantpro.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/KAS_analysis_6month.pdf Towards the end is a slide that shows reasons for discarding. The majority were biopsy findings (probably some infection or precancerous lesion) no donor found in time (Not all organs are a match of the people on the transplant lists)

Comment: Not a transplant surgeon, but... we're not going to rush to put a mediocre kidney in someone when that kidney may not do well in the long term. There's always a chance of developing renal failure again - and, if you've already exposed the patient to those foreign antigens on the donor kidney, then they are even more highly sensitized to any future transplant kidneys.